# How to handle nested params in rails controller.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I have params that are coming into the controller looking like this:

```
      {
        invitee: {
          first_name: first_name,
          last_name: last_name,
          email: email,
          state: state,
        },
        invitor: { sender_uid: sender_uid }
      }
```

So there are two keys, `invitee` and `invitor` and their values are hashes. What's a good way to handle them in the strong params? Would it be useful to add a top level key to this hash so I can use `require` in the strong params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do like below

```
params.permit(invitee: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :state], invitor: [:sender_uid]
```